# How do I inject a value from class decorator to method decorator in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have started using decorators in TypeScript and it works, I created Get, Post, Put and Delete decorators that I can add to controller methods and that take `path`as argument, and it works. But I want to be able to set a default path with a class decorator. As of now, when i console.log `_target`in any method decorator, i get an empty object. Expected behavior: I want the _target variable to have the path parameter, set by the Controller class decorator. My code is:

```
@Controller("/api/auth") // class decorator
export function Controller(path: string): ClassDecorator {
  return function (constructor: Function) {
    constructor.prototype.path = path;
  };
}
```

```
@Get("/api/auth/init") // method decorator
export function Get(path: string): MethodDecorator {
  return function (
    _target: any,
    _propertyKey: string | Symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ): void {
    const response = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
      try {
        return await descriptor.value(req, res);
      } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).send({ error: "Server Error" });
      }
    };

    let parsedPath: string;

    console.log(_target); // prints {}, expected: {path: "/api/auth"}

    if (_target.path) {
      parsedPath = _target.path + path;
    } else {
      parsedPath = path;
    }

    routes.push({
      path: parsedPath,
      response,
      method: "get",
    });
  };
}
```

How do I implement this functionality?

Comment: i added a console.log to the class decorator, it logs AFTER the method decorator. what do i do?

Comment: the _target parameter in the Get decorator is just an empty object. why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with some help from a guy on discord. for those with the same issue in the future, here is a solution:

```
export function Controller(pathPrefix: string): ClassDecorator {
  return function (constructor: Function) {
    Object.entries(constructor.prototype["methods"]).forEach(
      ([_key, route]) => {
        const {
          func,
          method,
          path,
        }: {
          func: Function;
          method: "get" | "post" | "put" | "delete";
          path: string;
        } = <any>route;
        const response = async (
          req: Request,
          res: Response
        ): Promise<Response> => {
          try {
            return await func(req, res);
          } catch (e) {
            return res.status(500).send({ error: "Server Error" });
          }
        };
        routes.push({
          path: (pathPrefix || "") + path,
          response,
          method,
        });
      }
    );
  };
}

export function Get(path: string): MethodDecorator {
  return function (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ): PropertyDescriptor {
    (target["methods"] = target["methods"] || {})[propertyKey] = {
      path,
      method: "get",
      func: descriptor.value,
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```